# Jboss 4.2 Datasource Connection issue

Tags: java, jboss

In jboss 4.2 connection are not getting destroyed?
in my application there are four different ds file. And application totally run on thread which keep on running .

Answer (score 0):

You would have to elaborate on your environment to get an answer on this. How are you using the data sources? Provide some code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you force shutdown the JBOSS session and the connection remain active. Please try to close it from Windows Services, or try to restart your PC.